# ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)

Tags: python, xcode, distutils, python-c-api

I am new in C, I am writing a Python C extension to improve speed.

here is my setup tool:

```
# file: setup.py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

extra_objects = ["/Users/rrg/Documents/test/aliyun-log-c- 
sdk/build/Debug/lib/liblog_c_sdk_static.a"]

module1 = Extension('pycproducer',
                    sources=['pycproducer.c'],
                    extra_objects=extra_objects)

setup(name='pycproducer',
      version='1.0',
      description='This is a Math package',
      ext_modules=[module1])
```

But when I run `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py build`, it shows:

ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)

ld: warning: **`ignoring file`** /Users/rrg/Documents/test/aliyun-log-c-sdk/build/Debug/lib/liblog_c_sdk_static.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/rrg/Documents/test/aliyun-log-c-sdk/build/Debug/lib/liblog_c_sdk_static.a

It also shows that the compile command is:

cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/pycproducer.o /Users/rrg/Documents/test/aliyun-log-c-sdk/build/Debug/lib/liblog_c_sdk_static.a -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-intel-2.7/pycproducer.so

I guess the problem is that I use a static library: `liblog_c_sdk_static.a`, but the library only support x64. However, when I run `python setup.py install`, the compile command includes `-arch x86_64 -arch i386`, which makes this issue.

So my problem is:

1. How can I specify only X64 in my `setup.py`? I do not want to support i386.
2. or how can I remove `-arch i386` from the compile command? The compile command is automatically generated by `distutils`(I guess) when I run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Finally I did not solve the problem, but I avoid it. I just write code on my MacBook, and compile it on a linux vm.